# Juju - Proxy issue

Tags: juju, proxy, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04, my juju environment is MaaS, however seems like my MaaS server doesn't have direct internet connection, for example:

If I do `apt-get update` it shows connection.

But if I do `juju deploy mysql`, he asks me if I'm connected to the internet, this happens after bootstrap.

This is my `~/.bashrc` file and the end:

[image]

In my `/etc/environment` file:

[image]

`~/.juju/environments.yaml` file:

[image]

Some other commands I did:

```
juju set-env http-proxy=http://172.16.1.160

juju set-env http-proxy=http://172.16.1.160:80

juju set-env http-proxy=http://172.16.1.160:8080
```

None seemed to work.

[image]

The error from `juju debug-log --replay`:

[image]

Some other stuff, I don't know if it's important:

[image]

[image]

This is from the MaaS server VM:

[image]

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is unfortunate. Looks like anything you set for the first time will yield that loud WARNING. Checkout this example:

```
andreas@nsn7:~$ juju unset-env http-proxy
andreas@nsn7:~$
andreas@nsn7:~$ juju unset-env http-proxy
WARNING key "http-proxy" is not defined in the current environment configuration: possible misspelling
andreas@nsn7:~$
andreas@nsn7:~$ juju set-env http-proxy=http://squid.internal:3128/
WARNING key "http-proxy" is not defined in the current environment configuration: possible misspelling
andreas@nsn7:~$
andreas@nsn7:~$ juju get-env http-proxy
http://squid.internal:3128/
andreas@nsn7:~$
```

You have to set the proxy variables before deploying a service. Can you double check that you did that? Even better, set them in the environments.yaml file directly and then bootstrap.